# how to implement hover effect on a QTableView row

Tags: python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, pyside2

```py
import sys
from PySide2.QtGui import QColor, QBrush
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QStyledItemDelegate, QApplication, QTableView, QAbstractItemView, QStyle
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt, QModelIndex, QAbstractTableModel, QEvent



class TBV(QTableView):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)


class DEG(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.currentHoveredRow = -1

    def paint(self, painter, option, index: QModelIndex) -> None:
        if option.state & QStyle.State_MouseOver:
            if self.currentHoveredRow == index.row():
                option.backgroundBrush = QBrush(QColor(Qt.red))
                # option.palette.setBrush(option.palette.Base, QBrush(QColor(Qt.red)))

        return super().paint(painter, option, index)
    
    def editorEvent(self, event, model, option, index: QModelIndex) -> bool:
        if event.type() == QEvent.MouseMove:
            if index.row() != self.currentHoveredRow:
                self.currentHoveredRow = index.row()
                self.parent().viewport().update()

        return super().editorEvent(event, model, option, index)



class MDL(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._tabledata = [['mike', 12], ['kk', 13], ['jane', 14]]

    def rowCount(self, parent: QModelIndex = ...) -> int:
        return len(self._tabledata)

    def columnCount(self, parent: QModelIndex = ...) -> int:
        return len(self._tabledata[0] if self._tabledata else [])

    def data(self, index: QModelIndex, role: int = ...):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None
        if 0 == self.rowCount():
            return None
        if index.row() >= self.rowCount():
            return None
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole or role == Qt.EditRole:
            return self._tabledata[index.row()][index.column()]

        else:
            return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    demo = TBV()
    demo.setItemDelegate(DEG(demo))
    model = MDL(demo)
    demo.setModel(model)
    demo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

as the title described, I need to set a hover effect on the hovered row.
I guess such visual effect cannot be set only be QSS.
therefore, how to do it in the python code.

And the code I provide above, the `editorEvent` method will receive MouseMove Event and get the hovered row index, later the `update` method will trigger the `paint` method, however,

```
option.backgroundBrush = QBrush(QColor(Qt.red))
# option.palette.setBrush(option.palette.Base, QBrush(QColor(Qt.red)))
```

these code will not change the background color of the hovered row.
I don't know how.

Comment: Changing the background on hover with QSS is possible (using the proper `::item` [sub-control](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-sub-controls) and `:hover` [pseudo-state](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#pseudo-states)): `demo.setStyleSheet('TBV::item:hover {background: red;}')`. It will alter the default style look, though, completely filling the item rectangle (which may not be what you want). Setting the `option.backgroundBrush` in the `paint` is ineffective, you should do that in the `initStyleOption()` override, *after* calling the base implementation.

Comment: @musicamante `demo.setStyleSheet('TBV::item:hover {background: red;}')` will only affect the hovered table cell, rather than the whole row, no such qss as `TBV::row:hover {background: red;}`

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part related to the highlighting of the *whole* row. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `backgroundBrush` of the option is ineffective, because `paint()` will create a *copy* of the option and initialize it with `initStyleOption()`.

What you can do is to override `initStyleOption()` instead and then set the background in case:

- the `state` is `State_MouseOver` (as you already did);
- any other "sibling" in the same row possibly contains the mouse cursor;

```py
class DEG(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super().initStyleOption(option, index)

        model = index.model()
        col = index.column()
        view = self.parent()

        if option.state & QStyle.State_MouseOver:
            option.backgroundBrush = QBrush(Qt.red)
        else:
            pos = view.viewport().mapFromGlobal(QCursor.pos())
            for c in range(model.columnCount()):
                if c != col:
                    r = view.visualRect(index.siblingAtColumn(c))
                    if r.adjusted(0, 0, 1, 1).contains(pos):
                        option.backgroundBrush = QBrush(Qt.red)
                        break
```

Note that it should not be necessary to override `editorEvent()`, but, even if it was, you should call the `update()` in *any* case, even if the movement does not affect a cell previously hovered.

In any case, you cannot use `editorEvent()` alone for updating, because it does **not** track *leave* events, meaning that rows will not be updated if the mouse leaves moves to a blank area of the view.

Comment: thank you so much, it works. 

Another question, how to get to know such professional knowledge about Qt, obviously, it can be really hard to find any tutorial as professional as you provide

Comment: i've updated the issue description, could you please give me a hand @musicamante

Comment: Please don't change the question by adding an issue related to one of its answers, as it makes the question very confusing. If you have a problem with an answer, first of all ask it in its comments, then eventually open a *different question* in case the problem cannot be solved.

Comment: new issue is, twhen the tableview's display is customised by `QStyledItemDelegate`, for example, with painter to draw some new design of the content, the `initStyleOption` may not work to show hovered effect

Comment: @Arthur `initStyleOption()` is called by `paint()`; if you override that, and don't call the default implementation with `super()`, then *you* must explicitly call `initStyleOption()`. Note that if you want to paint everything on your own, there's little point in calling `initStyleOption()`. If you want to change the font or color, you should do that *too* in `initStyleOption()`. Avoid completely custom painting whenever possible, and always try to rely on the default style painting instead.